# Should I create a new db or ship an existing db in android

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have ran into a situation where I have to create a db with large number of tables. When I wrote the code for creating the same, it became complex and confusing. I was wondering, whether it will be a good approach to create an sqlite db and ship it with the apk.
Which approach do you think would be good and why?

PS: on upgrading, i am dropping all the tables and creating new ones. No data is being retained.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why add an additional complexity or is it that you are creating/copying the database from elsewhere? Perhaps give an example of the structure and code where you are finding it complex and confusing.

Comment: I dont feel that shipping an empty, but large, db adds extra complexity. I feel its much more easier than writing code for creating the same. I just wanted to know, which of these options is a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you only creating tables for the database without predefined data, you can create the tables when you need them. But if you have more than 1 MB data (not BLOB) in your databases, you should create the database outside then ship it in your apk. Because inserting 1 MB data takes times and the Android system will complaining with "Application Not Responding" (ANR) dialog. User don't like waiting too long to use the application.

You can use [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to ship your SQLite database in your apk.

Comment: So it is always better to create the db than shipping it, if I dont have any data?

Comment: Yes, because it's freeing you from maintaining the database file. At least, it will reducing your app file size.

Comment: Instead manually hand code your SQLite database schema, you could use ORM. Or try [greenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/), it will save much of your time.

Answer (score 0):

### A few additional/alternative approaches.

My personal approach, which is an alternative to the two mentioned although an extension of creating the tables within the App, has been to create classes that a) simplifies table creation and b) caters for the limited dynamic addition of tables and columns.

It has the advantage of a single naming point (what i see as a pitfall of defining a database outside of the App) for the columns, tables and indexes.

It has the advantage of being directly re-usable. Although it has the disadvantage of the time taken to create the underlying classes (*this to me was a benefit as I learnt a great deal being new to both Java and Android*).

It does not require the complexities of dealing with copying/managing the database from the assets folder (*you say there are none, my observation is that one of the more frequently occurring Android SQlite issues on SO is in regards to problems copying databases from the assets folder*).

Some questions that could be asked, how does the App cope with deleting the App's data? If you keep a copy of the database to cater for this scenario is tying up the additional space (I believe it could be around 36k for just a database plus 4k per table (that is just from observations with a single database/table, so not investigated at any depth)). I doubt that the space for the extra code would be as much, but perhaps something that could be investigated.

> It does not as yet cater for foreign keys/constraints or triggers
> (never used any as of yet).

There are 5 classes DBColumn, DBTable, DBIndex, DBDatabase and SQLKWORDS.

SQLKWORDS contains definitions of commonly used SQL KEYWORDS e.g.

```
public class SQLKWORD {

    public static final String SQLTABLE = " TABLE ";
    public static final String SQLCREATE = " CREATE ";
    public static final String SQLDROP = " DROP ";
    public static final String SQLINDEX = " INDEX ";
    public static final String SQLUNIQUE = " UNIQUE ";
    .....
}
```

DBColumn is used for defining columns

These are used to progressively build a DBDatabase, which is basically the required schema plus various methods e.g. `actionBuildSQL` which will add any tables that don't exist, a complimentary `actionAlterSQL` caters for the addition of new columns.

For example to define a table (4 columns first 3 make up the primary index (3rd parameter true if to be part of the PRIMARY INDEX, else false)):-

```
import mjt.dbcolumn.DBColumn;
import mjt.dbtable.DBTable;    
import static mjt.sqlwords.SQLKWORD.*;

public class DBCardPayeeLinkTableConstants {

    static final String CARDPAYEELINK_TABLE = "cardpayeelink";

    private static final String CARDREF_COL = "cardref";
    private static final String PAYEEREFCOL_COL = "payeeref";
    private static final String USERREF_COL = "userref";
    private static final String USAGE_COUNT_COL = "usagecount";

    // DBCOlumns
    static final DBColumn CARDREF = new DBColumn(
            CARDREF_COL,
            SQLINTEGER,
            true,
            ""
    );

    static final DBColumn PAYEEREF = new DBColumn(
            PAYEEREFCOL_COL,
            SQLINTEGER,
            true,
            ""
    );

    static final DBColumn USERREF = new DBColumn(
            USERREF_COL,
            SQLINTEGER,
            true,
            ""
    );

    static final DBColumn USAGECOUNT = new DBColumn(
            USAGE_COUNT_COL,
            SQLINTEGER,
            false,
            "0"
    );

    static final ArrayList<DBColumn> CARDPAYEELINKCOLUMNS =
            new ArrayList<>(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            CARDREF,
                            PAYEEREF,
                            USERREF,
                            USAGECOUNT
                    )
            );

    static final DBTable CARDPAYEELINKS = new DBTable(
            CARDPAYEELINK_TABLE,
            CARDPAYEELINKCOLUMNS
    );

    // define full column names i.e. table.columnname
    public static final String CARDREF_FCOL =
            CARDREF.getFullyQualifiedDBColumnName();
    public static final String PAYEEREF_FCOL =
            PAYEEREF.getFullyQualifiedDBColumnName();
    public static final String USEREF_FCOL =
            USERREF.getFullyQualifiedDBColumnName();
    public static final String USAGECOUNT_FCOL =
            USAGECOUNT.getFullyQualifiedDBColumnName();
}
```

There are a number of `DBCOlumn` constructors e.g. `DBColumn(true)` will create the commonly used **`_id`** column. As can be seen from the above there are also various methods.

DBTable takes a list of DBColumns and DBDatabase takes a list of DBTables (and if required DBIndexes which themselves are take a DBTable and a list of DBColumns). DBDatabase's methods such as `actionAlterSQL` compares the required schema against the actual current schema.

I will then have a class such as the following:-

```
class DBConstants {

    /*
        Define the database name
     */
    static final String DATABASENAME = "cardoniser";
    static final int DATABASEVERSION = 1;

    /*
        Define the DBDatabase instance (base schema),
        it consists of the DBTable instances which are
        comproised of DBColumns (and optionally DBindex instances)
     */
    static final DBDatabase cardonsier = new DBDatabase(DATABASENAME,
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                    DBCardsTableConstants.CARDS,
                    DBUsertableConstants.USERS,
                    DBPreftableConstants.PREFS,
                    DBPayeestableContants.PAYEES,
                    DBCategoriestableConstants.CATEGORIES,
                    DBCardCategoryLinkTableConstants.CARDCATEGORYLINKS,
                    DBCardPayeeLinkTableConstants.CARDPAYEELINKS,
                    DBTransactionsTableConstants.TRANSACTIONS
            ))
    );
}
```

in my DBHelper I have (nothing done in `onUpgrade`, `onCreate` simply calls `onExpand`) :-

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        usable = this.onExpand(db,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
    }

    public boolean onExpand(SQLiteDatabase db, boolean buildandexpand) {

        boolean rv = true;
        if (db == null) {
            db = instance.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        // Is the Database definition valid to use?
        if (DBConstants.cardonsier.isDBDatabaseUsable()) {
            ArrayList<String> buildsql = DBConstants.cardonsier.generateDBBuildSQL(db);
            // Anything to build
            //      will not be if database is unchanged rather than
            //      if no definitions/valid definitions as this would
            //      be detected by isDBDatabaseUsable
            if (!buildsql.isEmpty()) {
                // YES so build the Database
                DBConstants.cardonsier.actionDBBuildSQL(db);
            }
            if (buildandexpand) {
                ArrayList<String> altersql = DBConstants.cardonsier.generateDBAlterSQL(db);
                if (!altersql.isEmpty()) {
                    DBConstants.cardonsier.generateExportSchemaSQL();
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            rv = false;
        }
        return rv;
    }
    public boolean isDBUsable() {
        return usable;
    }
```

In the initial Activity I have, which will apply any table or row additions and additionally index additions, deletions or alterations(delete and recreate index) :-

```
    DBDAO dbdao = new DBDAO(this);
    DBHelper.getHelper(this).onExpand(dbdao.getDB(),true);
```

In addition to this I use a single class per table (actually two as I also have a separate class for table specific methods).

All in all there are few complexity issues and for myself, having done the groundwork, is the better of all three options.

---

### Another option that could be considered.

There are plenty of SQLite Database tools e.g. SQLite Manager (browser extension) that would allow you to create a database and export the SQL.
e.g. the above database (well close to it) was retrieved from SQL Manager as per :-

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
CREATE TABLE cardcategorylink (cardref INTEGER , categoryref INTEGER , usagecount INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , PRIMARY KEY (cardref, categoryref) );
CREATE TABLE cardpayeelink (cardref INTEGER , payeeref INTEGER , usagecount INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , PRIMARY KEY (cardref, payeeref) );
CREATE TABLE cards (_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, cardname TEXT , cardtyperef INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , cardnumber TEXT );
CREATE TABLE categories (_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, categoryname TEXT );
CREATE TABLE payees (_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, payeename TEXT );
CREATE TABLE prefs (_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, prefname TEXT , preftype TEXT , prefvalue TEXT , prefshortdesc TEXT , preflongdesc TEXT );
CREATE TABLE transactions (_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, timestamp INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , cardref INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , payeeref INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , categoryref INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 , amount REAL  DEFAULT 0.00 , flags INTEGER  DEFAULT 0 );
CREATE TABLE users (_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT , userhash TEXT , usersalt TEXT );
```

(*note the above database was actually copied into SQLite Manager via Android Device Manager, so it was really generated using the Approach that I have adopted*).

If you source is **MySQL** or others then I believe that **PHPMyAdmin** has similar functionality.